# Spinnaker accessing UI from localhost using ssh-tunnel

Tags: ssh, kubernetes, ssh-tunnel, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I've installed spinnaker in kubernetes cluster, halyard is running in ubuntu machine.

To access spinnaker UI from my laptop as localhost:9000, I ran `hal deploy connect` on ubuntu and created ssh tunnel in putty for ports 9000, 8084, 8087 which is in my laptop to ubuntu system where halyard is running.

```
hal deploy connect
+ Get current deployment
  Success
+ Connect to Spinnaker deployment.
  Success
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8084 -> 8084
Forwarding from [::1]:8084 -> 8084
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:9000 -> 9000
Forwarding from [::1]:9000 -> 9000
```

But spinnaker is not connecting, and ssh even logs says - connection is refused...

however 've tried to running other application directly on ubuntu, created ssh tunnel for that and through localhost:portNumber in my laptop is working fine..

please advise.. thanks..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact ssh command you're using to set up the tunnels (including .ssh/config entries, if they're relevant), the exact error messages that you're getting, and the `netstat` output from the remote server showing the ports that you're trying to forward to.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on: [helm-chart](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/issues/1562), [spinnaker-deployment](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/4933).

Temporary workaround (until this is fixed) you can add:

```
spec:
    ...
    - --runtime-config=apps/v1beta1=true,apps/v1beta2=true,extensions/v1beta1/daemonsets=true,extensions/v1beta1/deployments=true,extensions/v1beta1/replicasets=true,extensions/v1beta1/networkpolicies=true,extensions/v1beta1/podsecuritypolicies=true
```

... to /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml

At the end restart kubelet.

Make sure you followed every steps from this [tutorial](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-to-deploy-spinnaker-on-kubernetes-a-quick-and-dirty-guide/).

Comment: Does it help ? Would you consider accepting it or upvoting - it will be useful for community.